# Are atomics in Ignite consistent in case of nodes shutdown?

Tags: atomic, ignite

I wonder if atomic types consistent in case of nodes shut down. For example, I have an Ignite cluster of three nodes with atomics configured in this way:

```xml
<property name="atomicConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.AtomicConfiguration">
        <property name="backups" value="2"/>
        <property name="atomicSequenceReserveSize" value="5000"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Would I get a correct value of AtomicLong if two of three nodes were shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll get a correct value because you've configured 2 backups. Atomic internally uses `PARTITIONED` cache template (it could be reconfigured by the way), it means that the cache has one `primary` partition and a configured number of `backup` partitions, let's call it `backupNumber`. In general `Atomic` survives after a loss of `backupNumber` nodes.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!